# Editing XML ProtectedString CDATA

Tags: node.js, xml

Third time posting on StackoverFlow so I apologize for any mistakes. :)

I am trying to edit the Character Data of ProtectedString

```
<ProtectedString name="Source"><![CDATA[print("CHANGEME")]]><ProtectedString>
```

It prints on the output

```
<![CDATA[print("CHANGEME")]]>
```

But does not save.

Code so far:

```
fs.readFile('./1.rbxlx', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  var result = xmljs.xml2js(data, {
    compact: true,
    spaces: 2
  })
  for (var i = 17; i <= 17; i++) {
    result.roblox["Item"][0]["Item"][i].Properties.ProtectedString = '<![CDATA[print("CHANGED")]]>'
    console.log(result.roblox["Item"][0]["Item"][i].Properties.ProtectedString)
  }
  fs.writeFile("./1.rbxlx", xmljs.js2xml(result, {
    compact: true,
    spaces: 4,
    fullTagEmptyElement: true
  }), function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
  })
})
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text.  Really. That's completely useless. In the same time it takes you to make and crop a screenshot, you could copy and paste the text itself, don't you think?

Comment: I apologize. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDATA does not really exist.

It's a way to represent a text value during serialization. "Serialization" means "converting a complex data structure to text" - and "XML" is the representation of a tree of nodes. The tree of nodes (a.k.a. the document) is the important thing here, "XML" is nothing more than a container format.

CDATA is not part of the document tree. After you read a file with an XML parser (such as `xml2js`), CDATA will be gone, just like all the angle brackets and the quotes from the XML are gone - what remains is the value it stood for:

```
console.log(result.roblox["Item"][0]["Item"][i].Properties.ProtectedString);
```

This will log the actual text value:

```
print("CHANGEME")
```

So you need to update the actual text value:

```
result.roblox["Item"][0]["Item"][i].Properties.ProtectedString = 'print("CHANGED")';
```

When the document gets converted to XML again ("serialized"), there probably won't be a `<![CDATA[...]]>` wrapper around the value anymore. That's a minor detail that you can safely ignore. CDATA is completely optional and XML does not need it to function.

The component that writes the XML (the serializer) decides whether it wants to use CDATA for a text value or not. In xml2js, this component is the `Builder`. You can [tell the `Builder` to use CDATA](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#options-for-the-builder-class) via an option, but your control over *where* it does it is limited:

> - `cdata` (default: `false`): wrap text nodes in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` instead of escaping when necessary. Does not add `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`
>   if it is not required. Added in 0.4.5.

It might even add CDATA where there was none before.

Overall: Don't worry about it. The text values will be correct with or without CDATA. Don't build software or processes that depend on CDATA being there, that's always a mistake.